# Parse json to DynamicFrame columns

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark

Hello I am trying to parse json file in following structure to DynamicFrame colums.I need every column separetely

```
changedFields|First Name|Last Name| ...... | id
             |          |         |        |  
             |          |         |        |
```

```
|-- employees: array
|    |-- element: struct
|    |    |-- changedFields: array
|    |    |    |-- element: choice
|    |    |    |    |-- int
|    |    |    |    |-- string
|    |    |-- fields: struct
|    |    |    |-- First Name: string
|    |    |    |-- Last Name: string
|    |    |    |-- Status: string
|    |    |    |-- Employee #: string
|    |    |    |-- Marital Status: string
|    |    |    |-- Address Line 1: string
|    |    |    |-- Mobile Phone: string
|    |    |    |-- Work Email: string
|    |    |    |-- Hire Date: string
|    |    |    |-- Original Hire Date: string
|    |    |    |-- Effective Date: string
|    |    |    |-- Location: string
|    |    |    |-- Division: string
|    |    |    |-- Department: string
|    |    |    |-- Job Title: string
|    |    |    |-- Reports To: string
|    |    |-- id: string
```

Comment: Can you share a dummy data

Answer (score 1):

```
df=spark.read.format("json").option("inferSchema","true").load("test.json").select(F.explode("employees").alias('employees')).select('employees.*').select("element.*")

df2 = df.select(df.select(F.explode("fields").alias("fields").select("fields.*"), df.select("fields.*"), df.id.alias("id"))
df.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use - dynamicFrame.unnest() function to flatten the nested json.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-unnest

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).